# MapInfo connect points in one layer to a single point in another layer

Tags: mapinfo, proximity, mapping, neighbour

I have two layers in MapInfo:

Layer 1: employees  - hundreds of points

Layer 2: place of work - one point with site location

I am looking to connect (ie draw a line) for each employee to the single place of work point (i.e. calculate each employees distance to work)

Can this be done in MapInfo by a tool? I can draw each line separately (Spatial> insert > line snap to edge) but I have many points so I'm hoping there is a more automated process.

Comment: The point behind using tags is to have subject matter experts who monitor the tag be able to chime in. If you create new exotic tags just for your Question, all you do is clog up the tag namespace.

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise. I'll try to amend the tags now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the SpiderGraph tool in the Tools window in MapInfo Pro.
This can help you create lines between objects in two tables where you can join the tables on a common value.

You can also use a SQL Select statement to achieve the same.

Comment: Thank you very much for your expertise, Peter